# Angular set disabled attribute in form builder

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have a reactive form in my app and I was creating it like this:

```
this.myForm = new FormGroup({
    name: new FormControl(this.item.name, Validators.required),
    active: new FormControl(this.item.active),
    value: new FormControl({ value: this.item.value, disabled: !this.item.active }, this.item.active ? Validators.required : null)
});
```

But now, I needed to add some custom validators to my form. So, I've changed my code to form builder like this:

```
this.myForm = this.fb.group({
    name: [this.item.name],
    active: [this.item.active],
    value: [this.item.value, this.item.active ? Validators.required : null]
}, {validators: customValidator()});
```

I couldn't find how to set **disabled** attribute like above to below.

Comment: Answer found in this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51951963/create-disabled-form-group-with-formbuilder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why you try to disable with disabled value. Use `disable` method of form instead.

```
this.myForm = new FormGroup({
    name: new FormControl(this.item.name, Validators.required),
    active: new FormControl(this.item.active),
    value: new FormControl({ value: this.item.value}, 
   this.item.active ? Validators.required : null)
},{validators: customValidator()} );
```

then

```
this.myForm.get('value').disable({emitEvent: false});
```

emitEvent: false here will prevent to trigger value change here.